# Laravel: paginate collection issue

Tags: php, database, laravel

This is my code:

The Model:

```
public static function myWishlist(){
    $id = Auth::id();
    $book_id = Wishlist::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('book_id');
    return DB::table('books')->whereIn('id', $book_id)->get();
```

The Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{$books = Wishlist::myWishlist()->paginate(20);
return view('wishlistCRUD.index', compact('books'))
       ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
```

But instead of showing me all of the specified books, it says:

> Method paginate does not exist.

I also tried this in the Model:

```
$book_id = Wishlist::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('book_id');
    return Book::whereIn('id',$book_id)->get();
```

But then it returns a collection and I dont know how to show that in my view.

Comment: `paginate()` should be a method on the query, not on the resultset

Comment: Instead `return DB::table('books')->whereIn('id', $book_id)->get()` use `return DB::table('books')->whereIn('id', $book_id)->paginate(20)`

Comment: You already `->get()` in `myWishlist()`, `paginate()` works on queries. You have a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use paginate after getting result.

You can do it in this way:

```
public static function myWishlist() {
    $id = Auth::id();
    $book_id = Wishlist::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('book_id');
    return Book::whereIn('id', $book_id);
}

public function index(Request $request) {
    $books = Wishlist::myWishlist()->paginate(20);
    return view('wishlistCRUD.index', compact('books'))
       ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but then I get an error: Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in /var/www/html/bachelor_thesis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php on line 577 and defined

Comment: Please check updated answer, you don't need to use get with paginate.

Comment: It worked that way! Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

First there is no need to use a `static function` [eloquent already does that](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-static-methods-not-declared-with-static-keyword?page=0).

And second you could use [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes) like this:

Model:

```
public function scopeUserWishlist($query, $userID)
{
    // Although a join would be nicer !
    $book_ids = Wishlist::where('user_id', $userID)
                         ->pluck('book_id');
    return $query->whereIn('id', $book_ids);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $books = Wishlist::userWishlist(Auth::id())
                     ->paginate(20);
    return view('wishlistCRUD.index')
       ->with('books', $books)
       ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ramy Herrira! Have a nice day!